# Adjustable divs and positioning

Tags: html, css

Hi I've written some code where I have create two divs wrapped inside another div. I have then create a league table and floated it to the right hand side. I have made the 2 divs on the left hand side small enough for the league to go alongside them however it doesn't seem to move upwards it stay in it position below the 2 divs. Also when I would like my 2 divs on the left hand side to adjust to whatever is inside my them. At the moment if I have one line inside the div its height is still fitted for 10 lines.

Should I use flex box for this? Any help would be much appreciated

`

```
        <li id="et"> <a href="#">England</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="Premiership.html">Premiership</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href= "#">Championship</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">League 1</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">League 2</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="et"> <a href="#">France</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Ligue 1</a> 
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="et"> <a href="#">Germany </a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Bundesliga</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="et"> <a href="#">Italy</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Serie A</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="et"> <a href="#">Spain</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">La Liga</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>    

</div>
<!-- Nav wrapper end -->
```

`https://jsfiddle.net/e2cmhrec/

Answer (score 0):

***[jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/e2cmhrec/2/)***

You `.wrap` has

```
width:70%;
margin-left:3%;
```

with some elementary calculation you have **remaining: 27%**.

But than suddenly you decided to make your right floated `#sidebar`

```
width: 30%
```

Even if you used erratically `width:30%` than suddenly your table inside the sidebar has:

```
width:120%;
```

Don't forget to `float:left` your `.wrap` if you want to accomodate your `#sidebar` to the right float.

---

Your `.wrap` has `display: table;` and you used for the first child `display:table-cell`. What about the second child?
Also why use `float:left` on a `table-cell` element?

---

To improve your `table.grid` look'n'feel you might want to use:

```
border-collapse:collapse;
```

also where you have yoru injuries and suspension cells, use for the `display:table` element also:

```
border-spacing: 16px;      /* learn CSS rules */
border-collapse: separate; /* learn CSS rules */
```

---

I've also seen a funny thing, you named a class `.ArsStand` for Arsenal that gives a red border... top and apparently not the bottom one, so you decided to add the same class to the team underneath... No. 1. try not to name classes related to a variable page content. 2. create your special classes **after** the common element rules (in order to overwrite them.)

---

Don't add height to tables... one day you might have more data and question why it's all so squished. Rather add vertical padding to your `td` elements.

---

You **cannot** have duplicate ID elements in a single page! `id="headinj"`

Comment: Thanks for your reply just wanted ask whenever i change the height of the left hand side divs the league table move upwards. Why is that? I just want it to say where is and not be affected.

Comment: @user3660857 can you show an updated demo so I can see your new issue? Cause i've added height to the inner DIVs of the left element and it all works perfectly well. (Have you  seen the demo link I've posted? Looks like you did not)